# Problem with figures numbering in poster format (baposter)

Tags: floats, numbering, posters, baposter

The figures have a wrong numbering in my poster.
How can I fix it?

The auxiliary files and the main code can be found in the link:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/bskjppttymwm

This is my code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% LaTeX Template for IAHR YPN Congress

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{kaust-logo-3.png}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{Discovery of Hidden Control Variables 
 on Non-Linear Biological Systems}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{Juan Munoz, Subash Balsamy, Juan Bernal, Ali Balubaid, David Gomez, Narsis Kiani \& Jesper Tegner}} % Author names and institution
{\includegraphics[height=9em]{karolinska-institutet.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Abstract}{name=abstract,column=0,row=0}{
How to construct robust dynamical models for biological systems constitute a grand challenge for the systems biology community that is still unresolved: 

\begin{itemize}\compresslist
    \item Several putative model architectures could be formulated for given biological systems,
    \item parameter space is massive for each model,
    \item hidden variables exist controlling the system, but we have no data for their temporal evolution. 
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3em}

\textbf{Our method HINNDY:} 

\begin{itemize}\compresslist
    \item using normal forms as universal, scalable, and minimal dynamical building blocks,
    \item Samples observations in the vicinity of a slow manifold.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Results:}

We effectively discover the underlying equations and unobserved hidden variables from data generated from the toggle switch, genetic oscillator, and Waddington landscape model.

\vspace{0.3em}

\textbf{Keywords:} Data-Driven Prediction, System Identification, Hidden Variables

\vspace{0.3em} % When there are two boxes, some whitespace may need to be added if the one on the right has more content
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\headerbox{Results 1: Validation}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{
\headerbox{Materials \& Methods}{name=introduction, column=1, row=0, bottomaligned=method, above=references}{

% \headerbox{Materials \& Methods}{name=method, column=1, row=0, above=references}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figure sub1.2 HINNDy.png}
\captionof{figure}{Method}
\end{center}


}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 1: Validation}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Fig2.1.V2.png}
\captionof{figure}{Discovered qualitatively behavior of hidden variables using normal form }
\end{center}


}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,above=bottom}{

\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\small{ % Reduce the font size in this block
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FUTURE RESEARCH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Future Research}{name=futureresearch,column=1,span=2,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

We will develop a data-driven workflow using machine learning (ML) techniques. We believe that constraining a ML predictive model using normal forms is the first step toward a more data-driven workflow to formulate systems biology models. 
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Contact Information}{name=contact,column=3,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

\begin{description}\compresslist
\item[Email]\url{juan.munozdiaz@kaust.edu.sa}
\item[Whatsapp] +966 545754957
\end{description}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 2: Discovery for unknown systems equations}{name=conclusion,column=2,span=2,row=0,below=results,above=references}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{Fig2.2 HINNDy.png}
\captionof{figure}{Figure caption}
\end{center}

}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS AND METHODS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Introduction}{name=method,column=0,below=abstract,bottomaligned=conclusion}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{FigApplicationPoster.png}
\captionof{figure}{Applications}
\end{center}

}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% \headerbox{}{name=results2,column=1,below=abstract,bottomaligned=conclusion}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block

% \begin{center}
% \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Methods2.2.png}
% \captionof{figure}{Applications}
% \end{center}

% }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general principle*, the figures are numbered according to the order in which they appear in the source code. Here the Introduction block (somewhat confusingly named `method`) is the last block in the source, therefore it gets the highest figure number (here 4). So the solution is to move that block up to be the first to contain a numbered figure, then it will get the number 1.

Note that this can created issues with setting the alignment, as the key `bottomaligned` only accepts values for blocks that have already been defined. However, it seems that this property is symmetric, meaning that you can just set it in the second of two blocks that you want to align, using the name of the first block.

An adapted MWE, with the introduction block moved up, renamed 'introduction', and the `bottomaligned` key moved to the 'Results 2' block. Furthermore I used the `demo` option for the graphicx package so I could run the MWE without downloading the image files.

*This is not always true, command arguments and environment contents can be stored temporarily and processed later (or earlier in subsequent runs), with code in between that has changed the figure counter. For example, a large floating figure can be moved down one or more pages with a smaller figure in between that can fit on the current page. However, you can assume top to bottom processing in many cases.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% LaTeX Template for IAHR YPN Congress

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Required for including images
%\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{kaust-logo-3.png}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{Discovery of Hidden Control Variables 
 on Non-Linear Biological Systems}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{Juan Munoz, Subash Balsamy, Juan Bernal, Ali Balubaid, David Gomez, Narsis Kiani \& Jesper Tegner}} % Author names and institution
{\includegraphics[height=9em]{karolinska-institutet.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Abstract}{name=abstract,column=0,row=0}{
How to construct robust dynamical models for biological systems constitute a grand challenge for the systems biology community that is still unresolved: 

\begin{itemize}\compresslist
    \item Several putative model architectures could be formulated for given biological systems,
    \item parameter space is massive for each model,
    \item hidden variables exist controlling the system, but we have no data for their temporal evolution. 
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3em}

\textbf{Our method HINNDY:} 

\begin{itemize}\compresslist
    \item using normal forms as universal, scalable, and minimal dynamical building blocks,
    \item Samples observations in the vicinity of a slow manifold.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Results:}

We effectively discover the underlying equations and unobserved hidden variables from data generated from the toggle switch, genetic oscillator, and Waddington landscape model.

\vspace{0.3em}

\textbf{Keywords:} Data-Driven Prediction, System Identification, Hidden Variables

\vspace{0.3em} % When there are two boxes, some whitespace may need to be added if the one on the right has more content
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,below=abstract}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{FigApplicationPoster.png}
\captionof{figure}{Applications}
\end{center}

}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS AND METHODS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\headerbox{Materials \& Methods}{name=method, column=1, row=0}{


\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figure sub1.2 HINNDy.png}
\captionof{figure}{Method}
\end{center}


}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 1: Validation}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Fig2.1.V2.png}
\captionof{figure}{Discovered qualitatively behavior of hidden variables using normal form }
\end{center}


}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,above=bottom}{

\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\small{ % Reduce the font size in this block
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FUTURE RESEARCH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Future Research}{name=futureresearch,column=1,span=2,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

We will develop a data-driven workflow using machine learning (ML) techniques. We believe that constraining a ML predictive model using normal forms is the first step toward a more data-driven workflow to formulate systems biology models. 
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Contact Information}{name=contact,column=3,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

\begin{description}\compresslist
\item[Email]\url{juan.munozdiaz@kaust.edu.sa}
\item[Whatsapp] +966 545754957
\end{description}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 2: Discovery for unknown systems equations}{name=conclusion,column=2,span=2,row=0,below=results,above=references,bottomaligned=introduction}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{Fig2.2 HINNDy.png}
\captionof{figure}{Figure caption}
\end{center}

}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% \headerbox{}{name=results2,column=1,below=abstract,bottomaligned=conclusion}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block

% \begin{center}
% \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Methods2.2.png}
% \captionof{figure}{Applications}
% \end{center}

% }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the layout is obviously not as it should be but it should serve to illustrate the general principle.

---

That said, a poster is a very different type of medium compared to a paper. While in written text you may refer to a figure several times from different places, in a poster usually a figure is there to illustrate the part of the poster containing the figure. It is uncommon to refer to the figure from the text on the poster, or if you do it happens while you are explaining the poster to the audience during the poster session, in which case you can point the figure out in person (maybe a bit more difficult for an online poster session but still generally possible one way or another). Therefore, on a poster it can be considered redundant to number figures or tables, and you can remove the 'Figure 1' part from the caption entirely.

Alternatively, since you explicitly define the layout of the poster and don't use `\label` and `\ref`, you can number the figures manually, i.e.,

```
\includegraphics{somefigure}\\
\textbf{Figure 2:} Some caption
```

This saves you the trouble of needing to shift the source code around to force the numbering, since the number of figures on a poster is small and you know the correct order.